# Advisor asked for my entire slide presentation so she could give the presentation at an international conference

Tags: advisor, conference, plagiarism, presentation

First, she never helped me on either my thesis or my slide presentation.
After my presentation (which she did not attend), she asked me "how to present" it to her so she could use it in the international conference.
(I don't want to do that, but I have no choice.)

Then, she asked me to send the whole presentation.
I sent it to her as a PDF file.

Later, she asked me for the "power point presentation" with the script.

I really don't want to give it to her.

What should I do?

P.S. She never gives anybody credit. (She did this before with my senior.)

**Update:** After reading many comments, I realize that I might be over-reacting. In academic area, it is normal that advisor could use the entire presentation of their student in the conference. (If I am lucky, she will acknowledge me)

I feel so bad about it but I need to accept the reality....

Thank you for all comments.

Comment: More contextul information is needed before we can answer this. For example, are you funded by a grant held by your supervisor which gives co-author status to all work produced by grant staff (such as an ERC grant)? Is there a clear reason why you cannot go to the international conference and present the material yourself?

Comment: Why did you stay with her after your senior? It's one thing to fall into the trap of a supervisor who does not give credit, it is quite another to repeat this. At this stage, probably you are better off just giving her what she wants and get rid of your project as soon as you can.

Comment: Sometimes there are unpleasant or wrong situations for which an answer is almost impossible. Consider that if she doesn't even remove your name the situation will be less dramatic.

Comment: @GrotesqueSI: Yes, my thesis was funded by the grant from government which is purposed by my advisor. She is my co-author. I could share her my figures, results and everything. I'm OK if she share my result in the conference with the presentation created by her (not her student). But asking me to teach her how to present my own presentation in the conference is too much. 
As far as I know, she is invited speaker. 

Thank you for your comment. I might consider ask her directly that can I go to the conference and present it by myself.

Comment: How long was your talk? How long is her talk? If you had a fifteen minute talk she's going to work into her 90 minute keynote, that's a bit different

Comment: a) Have you been awarded your (PhD? MS?) yet? Can your advisor retaliate? b) Which country is this in, and where is the advisor from? There simply are many (academic) cultures in the world where plagiarism, misattribution and theft are everyday behavior (depends on country), academics think they're entitled to. c) Would you be ok if advisor publicly attributed your work to you? (I wouldn't trust them, not even if I had someone in the audience)

Comment: It's **misattribution** (and thus academic fraud) when the coauthor's name is not displayed, let alone prominently (i.e on the title page, with equal billing to all coauthors, not just line 13 of acknowledgments on page 39)

Comment: @Azor Ahai My talk is 15 minute. I have no clue how much time does she have to talk.

Comment: @smci a) I have not yet award PhD. I also afraid that if I don't give my presentation to her, it would affect my graduation.
             b) we are from the same country. I am sorry that I could not tell you the exact country. I'm afraid she might know. (And Yes, I think this might be common in my country... but I don't feel better even it's common in my country)
            c) I will be ok if 1. She create her slide presentation by HERSELF with the figures from me 2. She acknowledge me.

Comment: Honestly I am surprised by everybody's answers here. Yes, it is normal that the advisor presents their students work, and even reuses the slides. but, Lucus then goes on to say that the adviser never gives anybody credit (as seen from experience with other students), that the adviser asked them to coach them in presenting their presentation and asked for the "script". And the community reaction is "This is not common or ethical, so it is most likely a misunderstanding. You are wrong. You should be proud that your work is presented, and you will be credited as that is how proper scientists act"

Comment: I've seen in the comments "the fact that you think it's luck that she acknowledges you if you are a main contributor is the real problem you have" implying (at least to me) that this is somehow a problem the OP as either caused or created (in their head?). It is very hard for PhD students in broken environments to speak up about misconduct and unethical behaviours and it seems like not a single person here gave the OP the benefit of the doubt that he has correctly interpreted the situation with his adviser, and not a single person advised on how the OP should react in that case.

Comment: Lucus, I think you are indeed in a serious situation. You might be missing some details, but the behaviours of your adviser you have observed and mentioned surely raise some red flags to me. Unfortunately, I do not have good advice for you, as you seem to be on one hand close to finishing your PhD, so taking any action to defend or stand up for yourself in an unethical research culture could cause somebody (your advisor) with power over your graduation to hold a grudge and prevent/postpone your graduation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From your comments, you seem to be worried not only about not getting credit, which others have already addressed, but also about the originality of the presentation itself. [Here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/138151/advisor-asked-for-my-entire-slide-presentation-so-she-could-give-the-presentatio#comment367430_138182) you write:

> To be honest, I will feel much better If she create the presentation by herself.... What I feel uncomfortable is "she will present my entire presentation with my own script."

Here's something important to keep in mind: this being academia, *the value is in the research itself*, not the presentation. That's not to say that the presentation isn't important; quite the opposite: you need a good presentation is to present the research in its best light, ensure that both the it and its relevance are properly understood, and so forth. But remember, you do not get academic credit for the good presentation, you get it for the research that was presented.

In other words, a good presentation adds no extra *academic* value to the research: poor research with a good presentation remains poor research. However, a bad presentation *detracts* from the value of good research and may delay or prevent its worth from being fully recognised.

Thus, if you have a good presentation that's a good thing, but its only real value to you as an academic is to help keep your research from being misunderstood or going unrecognised. Therefore you should greatly prefer that your adviser (or anybody else), when they present your research, uses your presentation if that's the best one available so that your research is seen in the best possible light. Further, you should give them any help necessary to improve the presentation further or focus it for their particular audience and situation, including giving it to them in the best format for modification and helping them make changes.

(In case it's not clear; this is all completely separate from the credit issue; if your advisor isn't giving your credit you should deal with that as suggested in the other answers.)

Comment: I strongly disagree with both "you do not get academic credit for the good presentation, you get it for the research that was presented" and "a good presentation adds no extra value at all to the research".

Comment: @jhin Really? Do you think that poor research becomes better and gets more citations if you put a really good presentation around it? Do you think that if the OP's advisor gave a really good presentation of the OP's research and then told people, "it's his research but I did the presentation," people would be citing her rather than the OP?

Comment: No, in those both points I agree with you. But I do believe that _provided you have done good scientific work_, a good presentation adds a lot of scientific value and you also get academic credit for it: it helps to disseminate your findings / educate others about them, which a) is an essential part of science (and thus adds extra value to the research which otherwise nobody would know about / understand) and b) helps you get more citations for your work, possibly at the expense of other works that may even be better content-wise but have not been disseminated as widely and nicely.

Comment: Maybe we're just splitting hairs/words here, but those statements in your answer can be read as strongly discounting the value of scientific presentations / dissemination. I don't know if that is what you meant, but that is what I (respectfully) objected to. Cheers!

Comment: @jhin Did you read carefully the second sentence in my third paragraph (the one directly after the quote)? As for "a good presentation adds a lot of _scientific_ value," how does the _science itself_ become better just because it's presented differently?

Comment: @jhin Consider the case where a mathematician A develops a proof of X but his paper is difficult to understand (i.e., he presents the proof poorly). Mathematician B writes a paper that much more clearly presents A's proof of X. Should be then get some of the credit for _proving_ X (scientific credit), or does A still get all the credit for the proof?

Comment: A should of course get all the credit for first proving the theorem, but at least in my opinion, B should also get (scientific) credit for presenting it more clearly / understandably / beautifully. But leaving aside the question who _should_ get credit in an ideal world, I was thinking more practically: it is simply a reality that people who present their work well often get much more academic credit for it than people who do great work but do not present it well, whether we like that or not.

Comment: @jhin So consider my proof example above in the current, imperfect world. How muc scientific credit will B get, in this real world, he doesn't try to "steal" credit by not referencing A's paper? Then look at the original question to understand the context in which I'm making my remarks. (I feel that you are considering my remarks in a different context of your own imagination.)

Answer (score 65):

As an advisor, I regularly use my students’ slides when I present my current projects. This is usually done within the context of high level presentations: I’m working on important project X; Alice and I worked on X.a which resulted in such and such, and with Bob on X.b which resulted in so and so. Claire and I are working with Alice to extend to X.c. If your advisor is supportive and showcases your work, she’s increasing its visibility and helping your career.

To conclude, presenting students’ work is not necessarily a bad thing and can help them a lot.

What is more concerning is that you seem to have serious trust issues with your advisor. She may be passing off her students’ work as her own but I honestly think that this is either a misunderstanding or something else. Advisors normally *want* to show that their students are doing well, not that they’re being totally shepherded by the advisor. This reflects *badly* on the advisor which is why I think it’s unusual.

If things have gotten to the point where you’re not harboring any goodwill to her, I suggest you rethink your options. If there’s a chance of a conversation to rebuild trust, try and have one.

Comment: Reading the comments: if my advisor were to present my results as part of an invited talk I’d be honored and ecstatic! That you are not indicates that you have major issues with her which you two need to figure out ASAP.

Comment: My advisor, even though he was the keynote speaker actually introduced me to present my/our research...  seems like the saying “all advisors are equal, but some are more equal than others” is **so** apt...

Comment: What your advisor did is really uncommon, and I’m not even sure whether it’s appropriate. I never had to give keynotes, but in grant review presentations I wouldn’t dream of dragging my students to present just to highlight the obvious fact that they’re lead authors. In keynotes people want to hear the speaker; other uncalled speakers is bad form. If I organize an event and someone pulls this off without telling me I’d be pissed.

Comment: Just because *you* scrupulously attribute other people's work to them when presenting it, doesn't sound like OP's advisor will do that... And it likely isn't about personal relationships, there simply are many (academic) cultures in the world where plagiarism, misattribution and theft are everyday behavior (depends on country), academics think they're entitled to.

Comment: @smci but that’d be really weird if she didn’t. I’m just not seeing how that would benefit the advisor. Your students doing well probably reflects better on a professor than independent work (at least in my university). I feel like there’s a misunderstanding or a trust issue here, rather than truly unethical behavior.

Comment: @Spark: Actually there are many countries where plagiarism, misattribution and theft are commonplace everyday behavior in academia. (Ditto: bribery, corruption, nepotism, incompetence, falsification). You'd be surprised.

Comment: @Spark: I would also was happy when my advisor presented a couple of things I'd written at conferences, because that meant I did not have to travel.  (I intensely dislike commercial flights, and am not real enthusiastic about hotels, either.)  It was IIRC reasonably common for advisors to do that, but they always made it clear that they were presenting their students' work, not their own.

Comment: @Spark Thank you for sharing your comments. 

I might not state it clearly since the very beginning. 
What she will present is "my entire PhD project". Nothing else. (No other student project)

I have no problem IF she create her own slide presentation with my results 
(I would be proud if many people could see my work). 
But what I feel uncomfortable is "she will take my entire presentation" and speak with "my script".

Comment: @Lucus, what is your concern here exactly? That she uses your slides instead of preparing her own? That she won't acknowledge that this is your work? If it's the former - I don't understand what's the issue. Presentation materials are really low on the order of "important things to fight with advisors about". If it's the latter, then this is something to perhaps start a conversation about. In particular, if you have no good faith in your advisor, you two should work it out or go on your separate ways.

Comment: @Lucus, when you two wrote the paper, did she contribute to the writing? Is it ok for coauthors to claim ownership to their own parts and get upset if someone uses the part that they came up with? It'll make it very difficult to present any paper with more than one author, really.

Comment: @Spark I concern about "My advisor using the entire powerpoint presentation with my script".  For me, this is the issue. I spent so much time on creating the slide presentation and thinking about how should I talk. I have to ask many of my friends to listen to my practice and give the comments (while my advisor didnot contribute to any of it). I revised it several times before my talk. Therefore, I feel this is not right. My ENTIRE slide presentation should not be used or presented by others, including my advisor.

Comment: @Spark Moreover, I feel that people, not only invited speaker, should prepare the slide presentation by themselves not using other's entire presentation (but of course, the speaker could use their student's data/figure/result).

However, after reading many comments, I start to realize that this is common in academic area.

To answer the questions, my advisor did not contribute to my writing. It is me and my friends contribute to it. My friend also use my figure to present in the local conference. And yes, my friend created the slide presentation by herself.

Comment: I feel like focusing on the slides is a bit strange. If you have issues with her not contributing and not attributing the results to you, you should mention them to her. I have regularly given my slides to my advisor for her use in presentations. You should address why this bothers you. My guess is that it’s because of an underlying issue you have with your advisor.

Comment: @Lucus Professors are very busy people. **Forcing her to recreate slides is a waste of her time and skills.** She is asking for the PowerPoint file instead of a PDF so she can integrate it into her larger presentation, which if it's an invited talk at a conference, is probably much longer than 15 minutes. Unless there is more than what you've explained, you should not be offended! Do you and her share a first language? It sounds like English may not be your first language, and perhaps there's a language barrier here that led you to misinterpret her meaning.

Comment: "A script" is not really a piece of academic work. The charitable interpretation is she probably wants it so she doesn't screw up *your* results. If she really does have an issue with misattribution, that's a different question.

Answer (score 18):

It's pretty common in my experience for advisors to present their students' work, **with acknowledgement of the students' contributions**. They'll often combine slides from several students' presentations into one talk for a conference, but they can also present just one student's work. In that case they usually say something like "The work I am going to talk about today was all/mostly done by my student, Whoever McLearny", at the start of the presentation.

**Prepare a version of the slides specifically for your advisor to present,** with her as the presenter, and with whatever acknowledgement of your authorship you feel is appropriate. This could be as simple as the first slide having you as the first author and your advisor as the last author, with your advisor's name somehow highlighted to indicate that she is the speaker. Or it could be having your name and picture featured prominently on an acknowledgements slide at the end of the presentation, along with any other group members who contributed. Or it could be your name in the corner of all the important figure slides, to show you did that work in particular, if the slides are going into a longer presentation.

Then you can send your advisor a nice pre-made presentation, and she won't have to do any extra work to cite you, because it will have already been done. It also communicates what form of acknowledgement you feel is appropriate.

On the other hand, if you think you and your advisor have very different ideas about how much or what form of credit is appropriate in the presentation for your contribution to the work, **you need to have a talk with your advisor about it**.

Comment: To be honest, I will feel much better If she create the presentation by herself and say that "The work I am going to talk about today was all/mostly done by my student", at the start of the presentation.

What I feel uncomfortable is "she will present my entire presentation with my own script."

However, after reading many comments, I start to realize that what my advisor did might be common in academic area....

Answer (score 10):

One benefit of her giving your presentation is that she will be actively promoting your work. For example, my adviser presented my theoretical work 3 times at 3 different conferences, and found an experimental collaborator to show that my theories were correct.

The more exposure your research gets, the higher the possibility for citations, which then leads to better career opportunities.

Comment: **That** is the correct answer. OP should be happy that someone is spreading their work "for free". There is nothing more to say about it.

Comment: True, but the scientific community will be aware that the results are the products of the OP's work only if the advisor acknowledges that she is presenting her student's work.

Comment: I guess I'm assuming that this will all be published.

Answer (score -2):

Look,  if she had done the same to  the senior, there's something afoot.

Personally, I am uncomfortable with the length she is forcing you to go for her -  like you've said, she wasn't present when you defended your thesis, and  now, when there's an international acclaim in the game, she wants to have your work to present.

She is your advisor, which means she is not your mentor. There's an important  difference between the two. Mentor is  usually accredited professor. Advisor is usually a senior student, usually in a capacity of helping professor manage his workload, but rarely they are professor themselves.

You haven't cleared out if she is professor or not. If she is professor, then no, you got no recourse available for you, at least not at this point.   But if she is a fellow student or just a person who specifically holds the title of 'advisor', and if there's a precedent -  a bad one - then you can complain to the board of professors, but  be aware you will have to have really good reasons and proofs at hand if things go south.  In academic sphere that kind of thing can quickly go kaboom and influence your  career later on in your life, never mind if you were right and she wrong.

So if you want to go that route, then save the emails,  all the conversations,  if you were talking over phone, write the dates down, etcetera. If it's an advanced level of research, what she is doing without asking for your input, it's an academic suicide at its finest -  for her.

I find it strange she wants to present a topic she is (presumably) not well-versed in  and you had to additionally practically dumb it down for her because she cannot be bothered to take some of her precious time and do her own note taking and research.  Well, fine, she can present your thesis, but what about the questions that come after the presentation?  If she doesn't  understand the material and its nuances, she will trip all over herself because she won't know the particulars well enough to explain this or that facet of the experiments of wording or something else.

It would've been better if you were the one to go and present the entire thing, because you know it inside and out.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Academia SE, I removed a sentence that can be considered offensive and may have led people to downvote your answer.

Comment: I have never heard of this "mentor"/"advisor" distinction and in fact, would think of it as the opposite.